# How to intercpet the url from CNAME in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, aspnetboilerplate

I develop a site with the multi-tenant option in C# .NET 4.6.1 with MVC/API with ABP (AspNetBolierplate). Right now the tenant is derived from first part of URL:

1. site1.myapp.org -> tenant SITE1
2. site2.myapp.org -> tenant SITE2

I some case I need to use a CNAME from another site

- app.mycusomtsite.com CNAME site1.myapp.org

Where is the best place to intercept this kind of wrapping and redirect all calls from CNAME to correct multi-tenant site?

 -- UPDATE --

ABP use

```
 var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
        if (httpContext == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var tenantIdHeader = httpContext.Request.Headers[MultiTenancyConsts.TenantIdResolveKey];
```

I not found a way to extract from HttpContext the CNAME property so I can extract the corret target site and replay to web browser.

So genearly I think/suppose that is possible manipulate request from original CNAME to identify the correct target site. Office 365 do that for webmail/skype for business

Answer (score 0):

I haven't gone live with my multi-tenant solution yet but there's a section on determining the tenant with **DomainTenantResolveContributer**

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Multi-Tenancy#determining-current-tenant

Comment: Thks Andre but the TenantResolve try to solve the URL not split from CNAME. I try to search if HttpClient have some information related to the original URL NAme